# ¿Cómo hallar el máximo valor de cada columna de un dataframe en RStudio?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, tidyverse, dplyr

Bs noches a todos:
Tengo el siguiente `data.frame`:

```
              Luma_01     Luma_02    Luma_03    Luma_04    Luma_05     Luma_06     Luma_07    Luma_08    Luma_09     Luma_10
MGP_MGP     1.0000000  1.00000000  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000  1.00000000  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.00000000
COL3A1_MGP -1.4248566  0.29277280  2.4772332 -0.4986536 -2.9125428  1.27324649  0.27965523  0.9049258  1.6423388  0.30769082
B2M_MGP     0.2585765 -0.19539417  0.2423724  1.4558758  2.3038878 -0.50995852 -0.29287568 -1.2059611  0.5080674  0.11119676
ACTB_MGP    1.4896388 -0.44635944 -2.9374108 -0.2318487  2.1599207  0.58709892 -0.09347122  0.8481642 -1.1976616 -0.03945772
EEF1A1_MGP  0.8363466  0.32373269 -1.0376648 -0.3267442 -0.4396582  1.30137710  0.31858854 -1.0875630  0.5639642  0.42172861
TPT1_MGP   -1.5764607 -0.61347713  1.3310090 -0.3457245  0.5174627  0.58742310 -0.06176777 -0.9383298 -1.2408054  0.21935965
SCUBE2_MGP -0.9026573  0.17143976 -2.9819200 -1.1235983  2.0745155  0.36948928  0.17529787 -0.5865497  1.9363953  0.19278796
KRT19_MGP  -1.8384828  1.01883153 -2.6468849  2.0384007  1.1849874  1.19218916  0.03475694 -0.9951005 -0.4703979 -0.16252095
COL1A1_MGP -1.7489864 -0.09643045  2.7187019 -0.1843953 -0.5007601 -0.69880961  0.37271541  0.7914487  0.7917059 -0.03007100
IGFBP5_MGP -1.1554821  0.92017968 -1.3746226 -1.8386243 -0.8697249 -0.34579395  0.10226092 -1.1133001 -0.4561358 -0.13694174
RPL3_MGP    1.6082191  0.66272554 -1.6840326 -0.6960999  1.3872781 -0.15339277 -0.11789818 -1.1102034  1.4670123 -0.12432836
AZGP1_MGP  -0.7082186 -0.34144120 -1.6766036 -1.2005131 -1.6547410  0.01942044 -0.18454484  0.9389360 -1.8779968  0.20538122
FN1_MGP     1.8118877  0.22697722  2.3597390  1.9975913 -2.3170588  0.71850010  0.27790423  0.9803370  1.9978485 -0.22133486
COL1A2_MGP -0.6824670 -0.89980703  3.1159683 -1.3903011 -2.4222162 -0.98365656  0.27280041  1.1488480  1.2535313  0.32964319
RPLP0_MGP   1.7080536 -0.29147483  2.8786034  2.1031238  0.4215034 -0.83906888 -0.03992623 -1.2187066 -0.2300023 -0.10551406
```

Donde se describen diferentes valores por cada par de genes (i. e. MGP_MGP, COL3A1_MGP, etc) por cada columna (Luma_01, Luma_02, etc). Ahora, quisiera me puedan ayudar por favor en lo siguiente:

Preciso de ordenar los 10 valores más altos cada de columna del `data.frame` por su valor su valor absoluto y que pueda guardar cada columna (Luma_01, Luma_02, ... ) en un `data.frame` individual para luego ser exportado a un archivo `csv.` individual también, es decir, en este caso podríamos tener 10 `data.frame`ordenados todos por sus valores más altos por fila para guardarlos en archivos `csv.` por cada `data.frame`.

Espero haberme explicado,
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una solución con R base:

```
lapply(colnames(df),
       FUN=function(col) {
           df[order(-abs(df[,col]))[1:10], ]
         }
       ) -> lista_df
```

Básicamente:

- Iteramos por todas las columnas
- Obtenemos las 10 filas con ordenadas decrecientemente por la columna en cuestión
- Retornamos finalmente una lista con 10 elementos/data.frames

Algo similar mediante `purrr`:

```
map(
  colnames(df),
  ~df[order(-abs(df[,.x]))[1:10], ]
)
```